# Is it realistic to have 7 months in a year?

Tags: planets, astronomy

I'm aware of the property of the number $2520$. It's divisible by all integer numbers from $1$ to $10$.

One of the factorizations of $2520$ is $7×360$.

It came to my mind to make a habitable planet that revolves around its star every $2520$ days. It has $7$ months (also the number of days in an Earth week) and each month has $360$ days (near the number of days in an Earth year). So the Earth completes every $7$ years about $36.8$ Earth days later than the planet does every one orbit.

But is it realistic to have $7$ months in a year?

Please read my own answer too.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147798/discussion-on-question-by-snack-exchange-is-it-realistic-to-have-7-months-in-a-y); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized if my planet has a moon it's impossible for it to have a calendar with $7$ months of $360$ days.

Based on [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3549631/) paper:

> The longest possible length of a satellite's day compatible with Hill stability has been shown to be about $\frac{1}{9}P_b$, $P_b$ being the planet's orbital period about the star (Kipping, 2009a)

So the moon should orbit around the planet in $280$ days or less. Of course this is the orbital period of the moon. We need the synodic period of it for the calendar:

For a planet-moon system we have: $\frac{1}{P_b}=\frac{1}{P_m}-\frac{1}{P_s}$, where $P_b$ is the planet's orbital period, $P_m$ is the moon's orbital period, and $P_s$ is the moon's synodic period.

Plugging in the numbers we have synodic period to be exactly $315$ days. So the calendar has $8$ months of $315$ days (we can say $4$ seasons of $2$ months each). (or more months with fewer days). We can even set it to have $12$ months just like Earth which has a synodic period of $210$ days long. But the problem is that the orbital period would be a non integer number of $\frac{2520}{13}$ in this case (about $194$ days). On the other hand if we have $210$ days as the orbital period then the synodic period would be $\frac{2520}{11}$ days (about $229$) which corresponds to $11$ months.

But if the planet doesn't have a moon a calendar with $7$ months is possible.

**Update**: Related to the question: Thanks to M.A. Golding's answer I calculated the innermost and outermost parts of habitable zone of a typical A2V star using the information on the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-type_main-sequence_star) article (see the first table there), and using the formulas $\sqrt{\frac{L_s}{1.1}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{L_s}{0.53}}$, where $L_s$ is the luminosity of the star in reference to the Sun. The innermost and outernmost parts of the habitable zone were about $700$ million km and $1$ billion km farther from the star respectively. I also calculated the semi-major axis of the planet's orbit using the formula in [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) article and  it turned to be about $680$ million km! So it is about $20$ million km closer to the star than the innermost parts of the habitable zone. So life may not exist in my hypothetical planet at all to have a calendar.

That said I continued to find the properties of the moon. If it wants to complete an orbit every $280$ days as I told you before, and if it wants to be in a distance from its planet similar to the distance of the Moon from Earth, the planet should have a mass of about $5.77612×10^{22}$ kg (the Moon of the Earth is about $1.26$ times more massive than this planet!). Also, the hill sphere of the planet has a [radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) of about $1.153$ million km in this scenario.

But if we say the planet is as massive as the Earth then the hill sphere would be about $5.4$ million km and the moon is in a distance of about $1.8$ million km.

Of course these were calculated using a $280$ day orbital period for the moon. The results surely differ for a $\frac{2520}{13}$ day orbital period (Hill sphere of the planet of course doesn't relate to the orbital period of the moon).

**Update 2**: If the orbital period of the planet is $27720$ or $360360$ days long then the non-integer problem of synodic or orbital periods of the moon that I mentioned above will solve. In fact, the synodic period will be an integer in $27720$ day planet's orbital period (if we assume the orbital period of the moon to be $\frac{1}{12}$ of the planet's orbital period). And both synodic and orbital periods will be integers in the case of $360360$ day orbital period of the planet if we assume the synodic and/or orbital periods of the moon to be again $\frac{1}{12}$ of the orbital period of the parent planet.

Comment: What if your planet orbits a binary star, and from the perspective of the people on the planet those two stars visibly orbit each other with a period of 360 days? that would be something a culture could use as a natural calendar interval.

Comment: That's not visibe though. The stars are so bright in the sky. One can't look at them even for a second, unless they use a filter.

Comment: so there should always be at least 9 months in a year?

Comment: @njzk2 No. You didn't get the point. $9$ isn't the number of months. it's the minimum ratio of planet's orbital period to the moon's orbital period. It means the Moon of the Earth can't have an orbital period of more than about $40$ days. And you can find the maximum synodic period from the maximum orbital period. Also, I clearly said that in my imaginary world the calendar has at least $8$ months. $8$ is smaller than $9$. (the number of months = the length of a year ÷ the synodic period)

Comment: that's what I'm saying (except I confused the synodic period for the actual period, my bad): if a month is, historically, a rotation of the moon around its planet, then it's impossible to have worlds with less than 8 (lunar) months. (a moon rotational period of 1/9 of a years gives a synodic period of 1/8 of a year). Interesting to think that there is a universal limit to this value

Comment: Yes, that's true. Of course, all months are lunar. We don't have a solar month, do we?

Comment: BTW, rotation stands for day and night. It's revolution that stands for a year.

Comment: @SnackExchange, I can glance at the noon sun long enough to tell that it appears as a disc, and  setting and rising sun can be observed intently,  but the binary need not be observed directly it's phase will be obvious in the width of the penumbra - the blurry edge of shadows. Thus the stars can be indirectly observed by looking at the shadows they produce.  but morning or evening observation would probably be sufficient.

Comment: @njzk2 A user calculated the days on my planet to be $\frac{6}{7}$ Earth days. Can you please tell me how they reached this number?

Answer (score 35):

The choice of the number of months in a calendar is very much arbitrary.

For example the Roman calendar before Julius Caesar reform had 10 solar months, 2 months and a leap year were added with his reform to synch it with the lunar cycles and with the seasons.

So the 12 months come from conveniently matching the 12 lunar cycles in 1 year, but it could have been 24, 36, 48, 60 and so on. Even the French revolutionaries and their base 10 systems left 12 months in the revolutionary calendar, only fixing the days of each month to 30.

If you want to make your calendar feel more real, try therefore to have some recurring astronomical phenomena having a similar periodicity, same as is the Moon for us. This could be, just as an example, a moon completing 7 cycles in 1 year, or 2 moons having 7 conjunctions in 1 year.

Comment: Do you mean the planet to be tidally locked to its star by similar peridicity?

Comment: "a moon completing 7 cycles in 1 year". Do you mean 1 Earth year or 1 this planet year?

Comment: @SnackExchange Unless this is some kind of interstellar colony, you have to think like one of the natives of your planet. Since they supposedly don't know Earth, everything will be relative to your planet/solar system, not to this unknown Earth .

Comment: Roman months were always lunar in nature. The early calendar didn't have named months for the two winter moons (presumably because there was little practical purpose in differentiating one moon from the other during the winter, agricultural off-season). The final two months were added in the pre-Republican period, long before Caesar's reforms. As for the French, they were obsessed with decimal systems and had little or no concern for "natural" subdivisions of the year.

Comment: Lunar months don't line up with solar years either. The lunar phases recur at the same time of the year after about 235 months or 19 years, which are strange numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle

Comment: @qwr: Indeed, there are approximately 12.3683 lunar months in a year.  The Hebrew and Chinese calendars deal with this by adding intercalary months as needed.  The Islamic calendar deals with it by having a 354-day "year" that drifts through the seasons.

Comment: @qwr What about 33 years cycle? For example I've heard that if a certain day of a month in Islamic calendar wants to fit on a certain day of a Gregorian month again, about 33 years should pass.

Comment: just to clarify, the number of months _is_ arbitrary *but* you still need the right number of days in the months. the pre ceaser calendar is objectively *wrong* because it ignores 61 days of the year. We can remove months, but then the days will need to be added to the remaining months.

Comment: @Aequitas As already pointed out, the "pre-Caesar calendar" is a misunderstanding both of when things changed (the 12-month calendar predated Julius Caesar by several centuries) and what they changed from (it's lost in legends, but if it really existed, the 10-month calendar probably used some form of "intercalation", or a single long "winter" for the extra days). That said, the only thing that would make ten 30-day months "wrong" is if you _claimed_ they aligned to a solar year, rather than just a "decimonth"; there is no natural phenomenon aligning to "7 days in a week", after all.

Comment: @IMSoP: As I understand it, the Roman calendar originally left the "winter" period unnumbered.  This is because the calendar was tied to *agricultural* events, so it wasn't needed when crops weren't being grown.  But eventually, people realized that the idea of *scheduling* things could be generalized to things other than planting, tending, or harvesting crops.

Comment: The Roman 10 month calendar only covered the warmer 304 days out of the year for an average of **30.4 days each** which is the same as the modern calendar.

Answer (score 17):

Humans have ordered days into weeks, months, and years to allow planning of their activities. Unfortunately, there is no *exact* match between the [orbital periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) of the Moon and Earth and the rotation of Earth. The mismatch between the lunar month and the year caused various workarounds and formulas, ending in the [Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) calendar reforms.

So assume you have a world with an orbital period of roughly 2,520 (local) days. The people living there are *roughly* comparable to humans, who have a life expectancy of about 25,200 days (ten orbits), and who could be argued to be reasonably mature at 5,040 days (two orbits) and fully mature at 7,560 days (three orbits). Say a child should go to school after the first birthday, finish school and either go to college or an apprenticeship by the second birthday, not marry before the third birthday, and retire after the tenth birthday.

But this year is inconveniently long for many day-to-day purposes. So it gets divided into 7 'seasons' based on climate and crops. If they have 2,520 days between harvests, they must have a habit of growing and storing food for the bad times. Say some staple crops have roughly 360-day sowing-growing-harvesting period, and it is possible to fit four growing periods with a [crop rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norfolk_four-course_system) system into each year. It may be that in a bad year one harvest gets delayed, but then the old farmers will mutter *'it ain't right, we should be planting roots by now, there will be a hunger winter.'

Call those seven 'months' *winter, snowmelt, wheat, turnip, barley, clover,* and *snowfall*.

Each of the month then gets sub-divided into equal sub-parts which are sized to allow e.g. the harvest or the threshing in one sub-parts. That's notional, you don't thresh turnips, and for things like paying rent or interest they're all the same length. 30 days.

Answer (score 8):

**Why 12 months in a year?**

Firstly, this premise is wrong. The [Ethiopian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_calendar) and [Coptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_calendar) calendars for instance have 13 months. Turns out we have [a lot of calendars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars).

Secondly, even in our Gregorian calendar, there's a hint that there hasn't always been 12 months. *Septem*ber much? Does that sound like the name of a 9th month?

An ancient version of the [Roman calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_calendar#Legendary_10_month_calendar) had 10 months, and *Septem*ber was indeed the 7th month. Romans adopted a 12-ish-month calendar long before Julius Caesar. 12-ish because it had shorter months, and thus an extra leap month every other year and February was somehow even more absurd than it is today.

The [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), enacted by Gaius Julius Caesar, simplified timekeeping considerably by having 12 fixed months of fixed length, give or take a leap day in February. This was inspired by two things.

The first is the Moon. The Moon goes through approximately 12 lunar cycles a solar year. This is evident in lunar calendar such as the [Hijri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar), which has 12 months but about 10 days less per year (which is why the 9th month, Ramadan, starts on a different Gregorian date every year).

The second is Egyptians. [Egyptians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_calendar) had a fixed 365-days calendar, with 3 seasons of 120 days, and each season divided in 4 months of 30 days, for a total of 12 months, again based on the 12 lunar cycles. The extra 5 days were shoved into a short 13th month. A proposal to add a leap day to that month inspired the concept in the Julian calendar.

The Gregorian calendar is largely the Julian unchanged, now with less leap days. What we can see through all these examples though is that 12, and occasionally 13, is the standard amount of months for a lot of different cultures through time.

**What about 7?**

7 plays a significant role in our calendar: it's the number of days per week. And the answer to why here is largely religious. And I'm not talking about the the hit book *The Bible*, whereby God creates everything in 6 days and then naps on the 7th.

Like most things Christian, this wasn't a novel idea. The symbolism of 7 comes from the Sumerians, who loved it so much that we got the [Seven Heavens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_heavens) out of it. Sargon of Akkad (an Akkadian and conqueror of Sumeria) is supposedly the first bloke to decree a seven-day week, a couple of millenia before CE.

The Sumerians though still had a [calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_calendar) of 12 months, of 30 days each, and leap months every so often, once again based on lunar cycles.

Still, Sumerian culture is probably your best starting point for a 7-month calendar. An unexplained divergence (lost to time probably) could have happened that it was decreed that a year would be 7 months (with lunar cycles possibly recorded separately).

Or some later culture appropriates the Sumerian symbolism of 7 so hard they decide to change their calendar from a fairly standard 12-ish months into 7 months.

---

**TL;DR this far**: Sure, why not. All you really need is people who love 7 a lot.

---

**How to make your own 7-month calendar?**

First we'll assume 365.25 days per year, Julian-style. You can always adjust the amount of leap time later.

- Option 1: 7 × 60

Sumerians used a 60-base system, from which we got our 60 minutes an hour and such. So with that in mind, let's have 60-day months. You have 6 regular months of 60 days, and a seventh super special month of 5 days plus a leap day every 4 year.

Bonus, maybe that's what inspired Egyptians to have their extra short month. Or maybe you copied the Egyptians, dealer's choice.

- Option 2: 7 × 52

There are approximately 52 weeks of 7 days in a year, so by transitive property there could be 7 months of 52 days. You'd have an extra day to tack on to a month for 365, and another to tack on every 4 year (either to the same month or to another month).

Which month(s) you chose is up to you. The first one, the last one, the middle one, or generally the one with the most significance.

- Option 3: 7 × ?

A more esoteric system could have e.g. 50 days per month, with the extra e.g. 15.25 days shoved off the calendar either into a byzantine leap month mechanic (like a leap month every 4 years, then 3, then 5, then 4 again, or whatever the maths ends up adding to), or as an extra unofficial intercalary period between the years (an 8th month that people don't call month and don't count as such, but still exist).

This wouldn't be entirely unrealistic.

Comment: The first section of this answer is great stuff (although it's worth noting that the Wikipedia page you link to says that the details of the 10-month calendar are somewhat in question); but the second part is based on a misreading of the question, which isn't talking about diving an Earth year, but "a habitable planet that revolves around its star every 2520 days".

Answer (score 4):

The division of a solar year into smaller periods is pretty much arbitrary.  If you want to, you could make an Earth calendar with seven 52- or 53- day months.
But a 7-month calendar is probably *more* realistic if there's something “special” about a time interval of 1/7 of a year (or 360 days in your world).  Possibilities include:

- The planet is a colony of Earth, and wants a unit of time close to that of an Earth year.
- The planet's largest moon has an orbital period of 360 days (cf. Earth's 29.53059-day synodic cycle inspiring 30-day months).
- The planet's most important staple crop has a growing cycle of 360 days.
- The sapient species has an average pregnancy period of 360 days.  (This would work well in a culture that treats childbearing as sacred.)
- A particular volcano near the capital of the civilization that introduced the calendar has a regular eruption period of 360 days.
- The people there count in base 360.

Whatever cycle inspires your calendar need not be *exactly* 360 days, just close enough that it makes more sense to divide the year into 7 instead of into 6 or 8.  So, between 336 and 387 days or so.

Comment: By eruption period do you mean a single eruption lasts 360 days or the interval between two eruptions is 360 days? Also, what's the significane of this? For example, in Earth we don't have a volcano that its eruption lasts 30 days or the interval is 30 days. The duration or interval between volcanic eruptions aren't predictable. Also, shouldn't the gestation period in this world take about 1890 days? (since in Earth it lasts for 75% of the year).

Comment: If 360 days is the synodic period of that moon then its orbital period is exactly 315 days. But if we say its orbital period is 360 days then its synodic period would be exactly 420 days.

Comment: @SnackExchange: My point is that you just need *some* kind of cycle (be it astronomical, geological, biological, or cultural) that's about 360 days.  Earth may not have predictable volcanic eruptions, but maybe your planet does.  Humans may not have 360-day gestation, but maybe your species does.  I'm assuming that you're asking about a fictional world, so just make something up.

Comment: @SnackExchange Pregnancy is about safely growing a baby to a size where it will survive once born. It varies based on how quickly the baby can grow (I'm guessing that's mostly about adequate nutrition) and how developed it is when it's born. It has absolutely nothing to do with the length of the year, so there's no reason it would be longer just because the year is longer. 360 days is [well within the range of Earth mammals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mammalian_gestation_durations), similar to a Dolphin or Donkey, so perfectly plausible for a human-like species on your planet.

Comment: Of course it ranges for mammals on Earth. From 21 days for mice to 20 months for elephants. Calculating a mean one gets 310.5 days.

Answer (score 4):

Month is not just something people arbitrarily came up with. The word "month" is derived from the word "moon"; there are 12 full cycles of moon per year (plus some). That is why there are 12 months.

There is probably some similar reason that makes sense that has made your people on your planet conclude it is a good idea to divide the year into seven epochs.

However, if it is not based on how a moon revolves around a planet, calling it a "month" might not be a good idea, etymologically speaking.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Please take a look at mine.

Comment: @SnackExchange Yes, you might need something else. Maybe the planet has seven seasons. Annual cycles on a planet where the cycle is longer might be a bit more complex than on our planet, making it possible to fit seven epochs that the nature goes through every year.

Answer (score 3):

## Part One: The Orbital Period of Your Moon.

### Months on Earth

On the planet Earth, the sidereal day is 0.99726968 days and the synodic day is 1.00000 day.

The Sidereal orbital period or year of the Earth is 365.256363 days.

The sidereal month or orbital period of the Moon is 27.321 days, and the synodic month of the Moon is 29.530 days.

So a year of the planet Earth is 13.369 sidereal orbital periods of the Moon, or 12.3689 synodic orbital periods of the Moon.

A calendar month in the Julian and Gregorian calendars is based on the synodic orbital period of the Moon and is 28, 29, 30, or 31 days long.  Other calendar systems have used months of different lengths.

### Moving the Moon

If the Moon was farther from Earth and thus took longer to orbit the Earth, a calendar month could be longer compared to Earth's year, and thus there would be fewer months in Earth's year.

The Hill sphere of a planet is all the space within a Hill radius of that planet.  A planet can keep a natural satellite in a stable orbit inside the Hill radius.

The Hill sphere of Earth has a radius of about 1,500,000 kilometers.  At that distance the Moon would have an orbital period of 210 days and 7 hours or 210.291666 days. So the year of Earth would be 1.7369 sidereal months of the Moon.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orbital-period

> The Hill sphere is only an approximation, and other forces (such as radiation pressure or the Yarkovsky effect) can eventually perturb an object out of the sphere.[citation needed] As stated, the satellite (third mass) should be small enough that its gravity contributes negligibly.[2](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf): p.26ff
>
> Detailed numerical calculations show that orbits at or just within the Hill sphere are not stable in the long term; it appears that stable satellite orbits exist only inside 1/2 to 1/3 of the Hill radius.[citation needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere#Regions_of_stability

So the outer limit of Earth's true region of stability should be about 500,000 to 750,000 kilometers.

At 750,000 kilometers the orbital period of the Moon would be about 74.333 days.  An Earth year would be 4.9137 sidereal months long.

At 500,000 kilometers the orbital period of the Moon would be about 40.458333 days.  An Earth year would be 9.0279 sidereal months long.

### Note on Synodic Months

Of course the synodic months of the Moon, which would be the months used in calendars, would be a bit longer than the sidereal months, and thus there would be few synodic months per year in the hypothetical calendars.

But if you want someone to calculate the synodic months of the Moon if it was 500,000, or 750,000, or 1,500,000, kilometers from Earth you will have to get  someone else to do that.

### Examples in our Solar System

Sponde, the outermost tiny irregular moon of Jupiter, has an orbital period of about Earth days.  So the year of Jupiter is about 5.8955 sidereal months of Sponde long.

Saturn LVIII, the outermost tiny irregular moon of Saturn, has an orbital period of about 1,624.2 Earth days.  So the year of Saturn is about 6.622 sidereal months of Saturn LVIII long.

Ferdinand, the outermost tiny irregular moon of Uranus, has an orbital period of about 2,790.03 Earth days.  So the year of Uranus is about 10.999 sidereal months of Ferdinand long.

Neso, the outermost tiny irregular moon of Neptune, has an orbital period of about 9,740.73 Earth days.  So the year of Neptune is about 6.1797 sidereal months of Neso long.

### Long-term Stability

According to page 3 of this article:

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf

> The longest possible length of a satellite’s day compatible with Hill stability has been shown to be about P∗p/9, P∗p being the planet’s orbital period about the star (Kipping 2009a).

The bibliography lists the source article for that as: Kipping, D. M. 2009a, MNRAS, 392, 181

Which can be found at: https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/392/1/181/1071655

But the giant planets in our solar system have outermost moons which have orbital periods longer than one ninth of the years of their planets.

Kipping was discussing the suitability of hypothetical exomoons for have having lifeforms, which requires that those hypothetical exomoons have orbits which are stable for hundreds of millions or billions of years.

But the outermost moons of the giant planets are believed to be captured asteroids, comets, or other small solar system objects.  They are not believed to have orbits stable for billions of years.  Thus their orbital periods can be longer than 1/9 or the years of their planets.

And perhaps the only story function of your planet's moon will be to serve as a basis of the calendar of the natives of that world for all of the thousands of years that their civilization might last.  So as long as the orbital period of the moon doesn't change noticeably during the thousands of years that the calendar is used, it doesn't matter much to the story whether the moon will escape into interplanetary space ten thousand or ten million years after the end of the story.

### Tides

One problem with moons is that the more massive a moon is, especially relative to the mass of its planet, the more important the tidal interactions between the planet and the moon will be.  Those tidal interactions will tend to slow down the rotation period of the planet, so there will be few planetary days during a planetary year, and also drive the moon farther from the planet.

### Visibility

You will want your moon to have a visible disc as seen from the planet, so the phases of your moon will be visible from the planet and and thus a synodic month of  your moon will be an element in the planetary calendar.

> The extreme crescent phase of Venus can be seen without a telescope by those with exceptionally acute eyesight, at the limit of human perception. The angular resolution of the naked eye is about 1 minute of arc. The apparent disk of Venus' extreme crescent measures between 60.2 and 66 seconds of arc,[5](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40746/how-would-the-characteristics-of-a-habitable-planet-change-with-stars-of-differe) depending on the distance from Earth.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phases_of_Venus#Naked_eye_observations

I myself have sometimes thought that the crescent phase of Venus might be barely visible to my unaided eyes.

And to make the phases of your moon more visible to the eyes of natives of your planet you must either give them much better eyesight than humans or make the angular diameter of your moon greater than that of a crescent Venus.  I guess that an angular diameter of 120 arch seconds or 2 arc minutes should be the minimum.

A full circle is 21,600 arc minutes, so a radius of a circle is about 3,437.7496 arc minutes long.  To have an angular diameter of 2 arc minutes, a moon should have a diameter 1/1,718.8748 of the semi-major of Axis of its orbit around the planet.

Assuming the moon orbits at 50,000 to 1,500,000 kilometers, it should have a diameter of 29.09 to 874.66 kilometers to have an angular diameter of 2 arc minutes.

And you may want your moon to have an angular diameter much greater than 2 arc minutes, and thus have a much greater diameter than 29 to 875 kilometers.  Especially since even a diameter of 875 kilometers might not be enough to make the moon a spheroid in shape.  If the moon is noticeably lumpy that will make its phases have funny shapes.

## Part Two:  A Year 2,520 Earth days long.

Here is a link to a question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40746/how-would-the-characteristics-of-a-habitable-planet-change-with-stars-of-differe/40758#40758

The answer by user177107 gives a table with characteristics of different types of main sequence stars.  One thing listed is the distance from a star where a planet would receive as much radiation as Earth receives from the Sun, which I call the Earth Equivalent Distance or EED.

The table shows that for an A5V star the orbital period at the EED would be 1984.29 days, while for an A2V star the orbital period at the EED would be  2,526.01 days.

So if your planet orbited in the EED of an A2V star it could have year 2,520 Earth days long.

But an A2V star would be much too massive and short lived to have a naturally occurring habitable planet.  Unless your planet was terraformed to be habitable by some advanced civilization, it should not have an oxygen rich atmosphere that multi celled land life forms could breathe.

According to Stephen H. Dole in *Habitable Planets for Man* (1964) a F2V class star would be the heaviest star which could remain on the main sequence for as long as 3 billion years and thus possibly have an oxygen rich atmosphere.  And some scientists might think that Dole was being too optimistic about F2V stars.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Anyway, a planet orbiting in the EED of an F2V star would have a year of 1,018.01 Earth Days.

**To be continued...**

Finally continued.

A F2V star would have a mass of 1.44 Suns and a luminosity of 5.001 Suns according to the table in the answer by users17707 to this question.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40746/how-would-the-characteristics-of-a-habitable-planet-change-with-stars-of-differe

A star with a luminosity of 5.001 Suns would have an EED at a distance of 1 AU multiplied by the square root of 5.001, or 2.2362915 AU.  Using those figures, this:

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orbital-period

Orbital period calculator gives an orbital period at the EED of 1,017.8 days.

According to the same calculator, a planet orbiting a star with a mass of of 1.44 suns at a distance of 4.093 AU would have an orbital period of 2,520 days.

4.093 AU is 1.8302622 times 2.2362915 AU.  1.8302622 squared is 3.3498597, so a planet orbiting at 4.093 AU from an F2V star should receive 1 divided by  3.3498597 time as a much radiation from its star as Earth gets from the Sun.  That is only 0.2985199 times as much radiation as Earth gets.

So the planet will be much colder than Earth unless it has an atmosphere which has more of a greenhouse effect than Earth's atmosphere does while remaining breathable for humans and/or the native lifeforms in your story.

A table in this article:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-type_main-sequence_star#:~:text=An%20F%2Dtype%20main%2Dsequence,between%206%2C000%20and%207%2C600%20K.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-type_main-sequence_star#:%7E:text=An%20F%2Dtype%20main%2Dsequence,between%206%2C000%20and%207%2C600%20K.)

Gives slightly different figures for a F2V type star, a mass of 1.46 Suns and a luminosity of 5.13 Suns.  A luminosity of 5.13 Suns gives an EED of 2.2649503 AU.

Putting those figures in the orbital period calculator, the orbital period of a planet at the EED becomes 1,030.3 days. The calculator indicates that a planet orbiting at a distance of 4.1119 AU would have an orbital period of 2,520 days.

4.1119 AU is 1.8154482 times 2.2649503 AU, so a planet with an orbital period of 2,520 days would receive only 0.3034116 times as much radiation from an F2V star as Earth gets from the Sun.

Can a planet be habitable for liquid water using lifeforms if it orbits its star at a distance of about 1.8302622 or 1.8154482 times the EED distance from its star?

Here is link to a table listing various estimates in the last sixty years of the inner or outer edges of the Sun's circumstellar Habitable Zone. By the definitions of an AU and of an EED, the EED in our solar system is 1 AU

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates

There are fourteen estimates.  Ten estimates give the outer edge of the habitable zone.  Those estimates give outer edges of 1.02-1.18, 1.004, 1.05-1.08, 1.24, 1.37, 1.67, 2.0, 2.4, 3.0, and 10 AU.

So some scientific estimates do indicate that planets can be habitable for liquid water using life in general at or even beyond 1.8 times the EED of a star.

Part Three: can You Take the Pressure?

I note that the 2.4 AU estimate assumes a volcanic hydrogen atmospheric concentration of 50 percent. And 10 AU estimate involves a world having tens to thousands of bars of hydrogen in the atmosphere.

One bar is equivalent to 0.986923 standard atmospheric pressure, since 1 atmosphere of pressure is 1.01325 bar. It is also equal to 750.062 millimeters of mercury (mmHg).

10 bars of hydrogen would have a pressure of 7,500.62 mmHg, 100 bars of hydrogen would have a pressure of 75,006.2 mmHg, 1,000 bars of hydrogen would have a pressure of 750,062 mmHg, and 10,000 bars of hydrogen would have a pressure of 7,500,620 nnHg.

Going back to Dole, *Habitable Planets for Man* table 2 on page 16 gives the approximate limits of pressure of various non toxic gases that humans can survive breathing.

The highest values are for neon, 3,900? mmHg, and helium, 61,000? mmHg. The question marks indicate they are extrapolated figures.  If those figures ae correct, a human could survive in an atmosphere containing up to 5.199 bars  of neon and up to 81.32661 bars of helium.

There is no figure for hydrogen.  Dole points out that humans can only survive in noncombustible mixtures of hydrogen and oxygen, and that a natural atmosphere is unlikely have large amounts of both hydrogen and oxygen.

Hydrogen-oxygen mixtures are used by deep sea divers.

> Hydrox, a gas mixture of hydrogen and oxygen, was used as a breathing gas in very deep diving. It allows divers to descend several hundred metres.[1](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf)[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere#Regions_of_stability)
>
> Precautions are necessary when using hydrox, since mixtures containing more than a few percent of both oxygen and hydrogen are explosive if ignited
>
> In July 2012, after about a year of preparation and planning, members of the Swedish Historical Diving Society and the Royal Institute of Technology Diving Club, performed a series of hydrox dives in memory of Arne Zetterström, who was accidentally killed during the ascent from his record dive using hydrox in August 1945. The memorial dives were performed using the same breathing mixture of 96% hydrogen and 4% oxygen as was developed and tested by Zetterström in the 1940s. The dives were made to a depth of 40 metres (131 ft), just deep enough to be able to use the oxygen-lean gas mixture. Project Leader Ola Lindh commented that in order to repeat Zetterström's record the team would need to make a dive to 160 metres (525 ft), and even today a dive to that depth requires planning and equipment beyond the capabilities of most divers.
>
> These studies scored a resounding success with a simulated dive to 701 metres (2,300 ft), by Théo Mavrostomos on 20 November 1990 at Toulon, during the COMEX Hydra X decompression chamber experiments. This dive made him "the deepest diver in the world".[7](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40746/how-would-the-characteristics-of-a-habitable-planet-change-with-stars-of-differe/40758#40758)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrox_(breathing_gas)#:~:text=Hydrox%2C%20a%20gas%20mixture%20of,to%20descend%20several%20hundred%20metres.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrox_(breathing_gas)#:%7E:text=Hydrox%2C%20a%20gas%20mixture%20of,to%20descend%20several%20hundred%20metres.)

Dole believed that humans could survive with about 60 to 400 mmHg of oxygen.  Thus a 95 percent hydrogen hydrox mix might theoretically be a breathable at pressure of 1,200 to 8,000 mmhg or 1.599 to 10.665 bars.

So maybe you should check the articles suggesting the habitable zone can extend beyond 1.7 AU with high hydrogen atmospheres. Possibly a lesser amounts of hydrogen will suffice at 1.8, and a world can have a atmosphere of several bars of nitrogen and only enough hydrogen and oxygen to warm the world and to be breathable.

Part Four:  A Planet Not Inhabitable for Humans.

A planet with a 2,520 Earth day year could have liquid water temperatures and have liquid water using lifeforms but not be habitable for humans who would have to wear breathing gear or spacesuits when they visit.

Or a planet could have a 2,520 Earth day year and be much too cold for liquid water using life.  There could be life forms using liquid ammonia or liquid methane.  Humans could visit wearing heated clothing & breathing gear, or spacesuits.

Part Five: A Double star?

If a planet orbiting a F2V class star with a period of 2,520 Earth days might be too cold for liquid water using lifeforms, maybe having it orbit two F2V stars would work.

If an F2V star has 1.44 times he mass of the Sun and 5.001 times the luminosity, two would have 2.88 times the mass of the Sun and 10.002 times the luminosity. the square root of 10.002 is 3.1625938, so the EED around two close F2V stars would be at 3.1625938 AU.

According to the orbital period calculator a planet orbiting at 3.1625938 AU would have an orbital period of 1,210.4 days.  And a planet orbiting two F2V class stars would have an orbital period of 2,520 days at a distance of 5.1565 AU.  5.1565 AU is 1.6304654 times 3.1625938 AU.  so the planet with a 2,520 day year would be a little warmer in this scenario.

Part Six: A Quadruple Star?

So what if your planet orbits around four F2V class stars, arranged in two binaries which turn orbit their common center of mass?  If the widest separation between the two pairs of stars is less than half an AU, the planet ought to have a stable orbit around the center of mass of the four stars.

Four F2V stars would have a combined mass of 5.76 Suns and a combined luminosity of 20.004 Suns.  The square root of 20.004 is 4.4725831, So the EED of the quadruple star would be at 4.47258/31 AU from the center of gravity.

The orbital period calculator says that a planet at the EED would have an orbital period of 1,439.4 days.  And a planet with an orbital period of 2,520 Earth days would have an orbital distance of 6.497 AU. 6.497 AU is 1.4526281 times 4.4725831 AU.

So someone might be tempted to speculate about a planet orbiting the center of mass of 8 stars with an orbital period of 2,520 Earth days.

But a star system with four F2V stars in two pairs with the two pairs close enough that a planet can have a stable orbit within the combined habitable zone of all four stars would be rare enough.  Going up another level to an eight star system would be going too far into the statistically extremely improbable as far as I am concerned.

For a planet with a liquid water temperature to orbit around 8 stars the maximum separation of any of he stars would have to be less than a quarter or a fifth of the orbital distance of the planet.  And I find it hard to believe in four pairs of F2V stars, each pair with sufficient separation between the two stars, and each of the four pairs of pairs having a separation several times that in each pair, and the two sets of four stars having a separation several times that in each pair of pairs, within the combined habitable zones of the four stars.

So it looks like someone who wants a planet with a year 2,520 Earth days long to have liquid water temperatures will have to put it near the outer edges of the combined habitable zones of four F2V stars.

And if they want human beings or other oxygen breathers to breathe the air they should search for gaseous elements and compounds which have very strong greenhouse effects and which are non toxic to oxygen breathers.

Part Seven: The Planet's Hill Sphere.

A planet's Hill sphere is the volume within the Hill radius of the planet. Moons orbiting the planet within 0.333 or 0.5 of the Hill radius will have long term stable orbits.

According to this calculator:

https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/KurtHeckman/Hill+Sphere+Radius

If the four stars have a combined mass of 20.004 Suns and the planet orbits them at a distance 6.497 AU and the planet has a mass of 1.00 Earth, the planet will have a Hill radius of 3,545,899.9 kilometers or 0.02370 Au.

The orbital period calculator indicates that an object with 0.01 Earth Mass orbiting an object with 1 Earth mass at a distance of 0.0237 AU will have an orbital period of 765.2 Days.

You want the orbital period of your moon to be one seventh of the 2,520 day orbital period of your planet, and thus it should be 360 days.  The orbital calculator says your moon will have an orbital period of 360 days at a distance of 0.0143356 AU.  Half of a Hill sphere of 0.02370 AU would be 0.01185 AU.

So your moon would be outside the region of truly long term stability  and it would probably be a relatively temporary moon captured by the planet.  But it wouldn't matter for most story purposes whether the moon would become lost into interplanetary space ten thousand or ten million or a hundred million years in the future.

I note that the synodic month of the moon, the period of the phases which would be the the basis of a month in the calendar, would be longer than the sidereal month of the moon, the period of the moon's orbit around the planet.   If a synodic month of 360days is desired, an orbital period shorter than 360 days would be necessary, thus putting the moon a bit closer to the planet and giving it a bit more stable orbit.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, given the appropriate astrological movement that can be timed to that interval, and the absence of any other gravitational force in the planetary system that could disrupt this very fine balance.

The word for "month" and the word for "moon" are etymologically related; there are about 13 full moons in one year, and early calendars had 13 months in the year, consisting of 28 days each, for a total of 364 days. Obviously this isn't an exact division, and observation of "calendar drift" required an additional day each year to align the calendar with the seasons, and then an extra day every 4 years when it became clear the calendar was still drifting. Add in the meddling of various self-important Roman emperors adding days to their namesake months, and well-meaning but off by a few years Roman Catholic monks trying to match "year 1" to the birth of Christ, and we eventually arrive at the familiar 12-month calendar with just over 30 days each on average.

In your world, you can handwave that gravitational tidal forces produced a more interconnected planet-moon system that exactly subdivided the 2520-day year into 7 360-day months. You're the writer, and while that doesn't give you license to completely ignore the laws of physics, I don't find this so farfetched that I'd stop reading in disgust. You're asking me to suspend disbelief, if you give me a plausible high-level explanation for why this interval is near-perfect, I'll buy in.

Obviously other elements of this solar system need to be established; a planetary year 7 times that of Earth's would indicate an orbital distance somewhere just inside the orbit of Jupiter in our own system, which is outside the butter zone of Earth-like solar intensity (and thus temperature). The asteroid belt, in turn, exists because Jupiter is where it is and is as massive as it is; the planet's gravity keeps the material in this orbital belt in a constant though minor state of flux, preventing it consolidating under its own gravity into its own planetoid.

Your system's sun would need to be slightly hotter to produce the "goldilocks range" of human(oid)-habitable temperatures on your planet, meaning it will need to be significantly more massive; that's fine, stars up to 200 solar masses still follow the multi-billion-year "main sequence" of stable stellar lifespan that allows a solar system (and, ultimately, life) to form around it, so there's little wrong with bulking up your planet's sun a bit. Your solar system doesn't necessarily have to be devoid of gas giants, and in fact their noted absence in a system with enough available nebular gas to make a star even more massive than our Sun would be an eyebrow-raiser for any astronomy buffs reading your story, but their presence will also be problematic given you want a perfect or nearly-perfect relationship between planetary and lunar revolution. Big old gas giants tend to induce minor variations in any such perfect subdivision until it isn't perfect anymore. Jupiter has a minute, but measurable, effect on Earth's orbit; insignificant most of the time (or indeed for the span of a human life), but planetary systems have a *lot* of time for these relatively small influences to add up.

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be if there was a second planet in the system, orbiting much closer to the sun such that its year 1/8 times the length of your planet. It would then appear a bit like Venus with a dawn-star/dusk-star like behaviour, cycling through dawn-dusk-dawn star once every 1/7th of your planet's periods.

If the inner planet was large and had a very high aldebo then it could easily be the brightest thing in the sky (apart from the sun itself), assuming your planet had no moon.

You could increase the orbital radius of the 2nd planet so its orbit took 1/4 times your planet's orbital period, in which case the 'month' would be the time between the 2nd planet appearing highest in the sky (either as a dawn or dusk star) and being hidden by the glare of the sun.